# Precise definition of Haar-distributed

Tags: probability, measure-theory, notation, topological-groups

I've been confused by the naming convention used in Meckes' book on Random matrix theory on the classical compact group that I'm hoping someone could help me clarify. The book can be found https://case.edu/artsci/math/esmeckes/Haar_book.pdf

I understand a left Haar-measure is one that is left-invariant. Assuming $G$ is a topological group then for all $A\subseteq G$ and $g \in G$, we say $\mu$ is a left-hair measure if $\mu(gA) = \mu(A)$. But I'm confused to what they mean when they say a random $g \in G$ is Haar-distributed? I presume they mean a random variable $g:\Omega \to G$ for $(\Omega,\mathbb{P})$ some probability space? And it's Haar-distributed to mean for all $h \in G$ and $A\subset G$,
$$\mathbb{P}(g \in A) = \mathbb{P}(hg \in A).$$
Honestly, I'm not sure. Also, does Haar-distributed mean the same thing as distributed according to a Haar measure? Would really appreciate the clarification.

Comment: I would interpret "Haar-distributed" similarly  to "normally distributed". So I guess $g$ being Haar distributed means that the law of $g$ is the Haar measure.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Do you know what distributed according to a measure $\mu$ means? Forgive my igonorance im not familiar with stats or prob

Comment: The law of a random variable $X$ is the measure $P_X$ defined on measurable sets by $P_X(A) = P(X \in A)$. The phrase "$X$ is distributed according to $\mu$" means $P_X = \mu$.

Answer (score 1):

For intuition the simplest nontrivial case to think about is a Haar-random element of the circle $S^1$: this means, to be very concrete, picking a random angle $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$ in such a way that $\mathbb{P}(\alpha < \theta < \beta) = \frac{\beta - \alpha}{2\pi}$. In other words we want to pick a random element of $S^1$ in a "uniformly distributed" way. This generalizes to any compact topological group and is made precise using the definition of Haar measure.

A random Haar-distributed $g \in G$ (which means the same thing as "distributed according to Haar measure") can be defined formally as a random variable, but that random variable is itself valued in $G$, and the function is the identity function $G \to G$. The important content of this statement is that $\mathbb{P}(g \in U) = \mu(U)$ for measurable $U$ and $\mu$ the Haar measure.

Comment: just a quick clarification, so we're able to assume that $G$ the topological group already has a probability $\mathbb{P}$ associated with it?

Comment: @asuuuka: well, that depends on what the author has proven so far. Haar probability measures (Haar measures with total measure $1$) only exist on *compact* groups. There's an easy way to construct them on compact Lie groups (which I gather is the subject of this book) and a hard proof that they exist on arbitrary compact groups.